# Facebook plugin for unity3D WP8 and METRO

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine

I try to use facebooksdk.net in my WP8 Unity3D Plugin. Facebook.dll and Facebook.Client.dll and their fakes in correct folders, but error occure. Is there any way to fix it?

```
Error building Player: Exception: Failed to run assembly preprocessor with command line       "Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed\Facebook.Client.dll" -injectCtor -assemblyPath "Temp/StagingArea" -pdb.[Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed\Facebook.Client.dll]
No symbols for Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed\Facebook.Client.dll
Injecting ctor
Error while in assembly preprocessor Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed\Facebook.Client.dll
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at AssemblyPreprocessor.Utils.IsBaseType(TypeDefinition definition, String name)
at AssemblyPreprocessor.Utils.IsFromNamespace(TypeDefinition definition, String namezpace)
at AssemblyPreprocessor.ConstructorInjector.ShouldInject(TypeDefinition typeDefinition)
at AssemblyPreprocessor.ConstructorInjector.InjectConstructorsForTypesIn(ModuleDefinition moduleDefinition)
at AssemblyPreprocessor.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook.dll use .NET Framework 4.5 libraries, and Windows Phone use .NET API for windows phone (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207211(v=vs.105).aspx). You cant export this dll to WP8